# Prove that if $a_k \in [0, 1] $ then $\frac {1}{1+a_1} + \frac {1}{1+a_2} + \cdots +\frac {1}{1+a_n} \le \frac{n}{1+ \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}}$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math

One of my friends gave me this problem:

> If $a_k \in [0, 1]$, Prove that:
>   $$\frac {1}{1+a_1} + \frac {1}{1+a_2} + \cdots +\frac {1}{1+a_n} \le \frac{n}{1+ \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}}$$

I have been trying this all day trying to apply things from AM-GM to Cauchy to Chebyshev to Convex functions. Nothing worked.

Can anyone give a solution or help. Much thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't feel bad for not solving it. Most because it's false. $n=2, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 0$.

Comment: Im sorry I made a mistake but the RHS is less than. I edited the question. Sorry.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Prove that $\frac{1}{1+x_1}+\frac{1}{1+x_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1+x_n} \geq \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1600051/42969) – via the substitution $x_i = 1/a_i$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $a_i = e^{\lambda_{i}}$ for all $i$. Define $f$ : $x \mapsto \frac{1}{1+e^x}$. $f$ is concave on $]-\infty, 0]$, so $\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i}} \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+e^{\lambda_{i}}}$, which allows us to conclude.